# How to test functions with PHPUnit in Zend?

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks, phpunit

I have simple question. Probably I missed something. Is there possibility to test normal function, not action, in Zend Framework?

For example, I want to run test for this function:

```
public function isMature($age){
    if($age>=18) true;
        else false;
}
```

which is located in IndexController. I've tried with

```
$this->indexController = new IndexController();
$this->assertFalse($this->indexController->isMature(5));
```

but PHPUnit says that I must pass instance of Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract to __construct(). Is it proper way to achieve this? How to prepare this test in good way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the controller at all to test your function.  Your code has nothing to do with Zend Framework so you don't need to concern yourself with a controller.

```
class MatureTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    /**
     * @dataProvider dataIsMature
     */
    public function TestIsMature($age, $expected) {
       $this->assertSame($expected, isMature($age));
    }

    public function dataIsMature() {
       return array(
            'mature' => array(18, true),
            'not mature' => array(17, false),
            'really mature' => array(99, true)
       );
    }
}
```

Just make sure that you are including the file with the function in your test class

Though you really should create some sort of model/service class that wraps this functionality rather than creating a function.

Answer (score 1):

It is not so easy to test such functions insinde an Controller when it´s not an action. I would move such "Business - Logic" to an ServiceClass or Model or what ever and test this.

```
class My_Age_Service()
{
    public function isMature($age){
       if($age>=18) true;
        else false;
    }
}
```

To Unit Test Controller Actions, have look at "Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase"
[Zend Controller Tests](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.test.phpunit.html)